# how to create dynamic function in php

Tags: php, function

how to create a dynamic function with php. eg I want to make:

```
<?php 

function update($table, $data=array(), $column, $value) 
{
   if (is_array ($data)
   {
       $q = "UPDATE $table SET $column WHERE $data = $value."
   }
   return $q;
}
```

how do I get when I call the function like this

```
$array = array(
    'id'   => 1,
    'name' => 'john',
);
update('user', $array, 'id', 1);
```

and the resulting value:

```
UPDATE users SET id=1, name='John' where id=1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php function update($table, $data=array(), $column, $value) {
   if(is_array($data) && !empty($data)){
     $toUpdate = array() ;
     foreach ($data as $key => $value){
       $toUpdate[] = "{$key} = '{$value}'" ;
     }
     $sets = implode(", ", $toUpdate) ;
     $q = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$sets} WHERE {$column} = '{$value}' " ;
     return $q ;
   }
   return null ;
}
?>
```

Just a simple example how to do that. You should remember, that you have to secure your statements by escaping special characters in your data.

Comment: then what if I want to add a special character?

Comment: @iwandede read about it here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$fields = array();
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
  $fields[] = "`$k`='$v'";
}
$fields = implode(',', $fields);

return "UPDATE $table SET $fields WHERE $data = $value";
```

But this is a **very** wrong way to build SQL stements. You may want use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
function update($table, $data=array(), $column, $value) {
  if(is_array($data) && count($data) > 0){
    $q="UPDATE $table SET"
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
      if ($i > 0) {
        $q .= ",";
      }
      $q .= " $field=$value";
    }
    $q .= " WHERE $column=$value";
  }
  return $q;
}
?>
```